# Is it not possible for true standing waves to appear in nature?

Tags: waves

From what I understand, standing waves form when the following conditions are met: 2 waves of equal frequency, amplitude, and polarization are travelling in opposite directions. So if any of those conditions are not met, then you will not have a standing wave. Any natural wave that propagates will have an amplitude that decreases as it travels due to losses. Such a waves would not be able to become standing since their amplitudes would not be equal. One could perhaps make waves that "appear" to be standing if one's measurement device is not sensitive enough to pick up the nonzero amplitudes at the nodes, but they should be nonzereo.

Comment: You can have a standing wave superimposed with a travelling wave, and attribute the nonzero field at the node of the standing wave to the travelling wave component. But without knowing why the distinction matters to you, I don't know if that answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Those three conditions are only needed exactly for a standing wave of infinite duration. Since the universe has a finite duration obviously such a wave is trivially not possible.

However, for standing waves that don’t last forever those conditions only need to be approximately met. Any musical instrument can produce such standing waves.

So this is less about the physical phenomenon of standing waves and more about the word “true”. By being particularly picky about “true” you can exclude almost anything that follows from existing. But is that a meaningful thing to do? I think not. It just means that the word true is truly useless because nothing meets the overly idealized criteria of true.

So yes, standing waves truly exist. You can decide if such waves are “true standing waves”

Comment: Yes, it seems way too pedantic; but I also did not understand why we cannot just engineer an almost-perfect setup just to satisfy the definitions. Like, we can have a double-slit setup, bent around with waveguides so that the equal-amplitude, equal-frequency and equal-polarisation waves are sent towards each other. Then the exact centre will have standing waves. Such experiments are quite easy to do with microwaves.